# Installation issue "pip install cx_Oracle-7.1.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64"

Tags: python

I want to install the cx_Oracle package so that i can have a connection between my Oracle XE 18C Database via SQL Developer and Python via Spyder so that I can directly move my bulky data from .csv file to oracle table in database.

"Only i want is to install the cx_Oracle package for Python 3.7 so that i can get Oracle Database connected with Python. How soever I know the code to import the cx_Oracle package and establishing connection in Python for database". Installing of "pip install cx_Oracle-7.1.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64" is creating an error.

I have installed the pip package and tried installing the pip package it got installed, using the below command;

"pip install cx_Oracle"

Then i downloaded the cx_Oracle(cx_Oracle-7.1.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) and executed below command in CMD using admin mode, which promts me error;

"pip install cx_Oracle-7.1.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64"

Command 1:

"pip install cx_Oracle"

Command 2:

"pip install cx_Oracle-7.1.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64"

The error is from cmd so unable to paste it here but i can have jpg file for the same.

Comment: You didn't include the error or the jpg

Comment: Error is in jpeg file which i am unable to upload could u please help me to do the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't think oracle libraries are in pypi (default).

You may need to download their tar ball and install it as pip install xyz.tar

Comment: The same I am doing but it is giving me an error in cmd I am unable to paste that error it has to be manually written

Comment: Oracle libraries cannot be installed with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in a csv file, you should use Oracle's SQL*Loader utility (which is available in [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)) or external tables.  This will be more efficient than using Python. SQL*Loader documentation is https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144

If you want Python for something else, then check the cx_Oracle [installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: I only want to move csv excel file data to oracle database table using python

Comment: I understand the desire to work in a familiar language.  However, unless you need to use Python to transform the data, its worth thinking about SQL*Loader or external tables.  These will load  big sets of data faster than Python.